# How do you debug typescript in Visual Studio Code successfully?

Tags: angular, typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code

I notice if you are using Node Package Manager generally you can have your package.json have something like this:

```
(dependencies and devDependencies omitted)..
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tscwatch\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tscwatch": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  }
```

Then you just get to the level of the folder you are at and type in

```
npm install
```

Then

```
npm start
```

And lite server hosts your application and typescript compiles to javascript.  Provided that you have ran the equivalent of your typescript configurations and have a valid tsconfig.json.  That aside I am wanting to debug the Typescript and just running into wall after wall getting it working.  I know you can add 'launch.json' that VS Code uses to do MANY types of abilities to start programs.  And a lot of them work fine for simple apps I find online, but not Angular as I am using it.  But when I try to do an NPM Start in the launch.json like:

```
 {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch via NPM ProAngular Example",
        "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
        "args": ["${relativeFile}"],
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "start"
        ]
    }
```

It will run but then attempt to open Visual Studio Professional(may not be the case for others) and then have an error like: "Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:(port)).  I have tried other configs for NPM for launch and other things.  I just want to debug the Typescript when it is done with Angular, is that possible in VS Code?

Comment: your title says visual studio code while the text says visual studio, please figure out which one you are using it matters a lot for the response.

Comment: It is Visual Studio Code, it is OPENING Visual Studio inadvertently.  Don't know why it does that with the config I use.

Comment: Why do you specifically need to debug in Visual Studio Code? Debugging using the Chrome developer tools debugger is quick and easy and that's why most developers prefer to do it that way.

Comment: You cannot debug Typescript in Chrome Tools can you?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below instructions in VSCode:

1- Download the [latest release of VS Code](http://code.visualstudio.com/Download) and install the [Chrome debugger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome)

2- Make sure Chrome is at least version version 59 (see [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug/issues/447))

3- Create your Angular app using [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)

4- Create a `launch.jsonfile` to configure the VS Code debugger and put it inside `.vscode` in your root folder.

```js
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome with ng serve",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200/#",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
    },
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome with ng test",
      "url": "http://localhost:9876/debug.html",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
    }
  ]
}
```

5. Start your Angular app by running `ng serve` in your favourite terminal.
6. Start debugging in VS Code by pressing `F5` or going to the debug section select `Launch Chrome with ng serve` followed by clicking the green debug icon.

Comment: This works sort of.  I still need to ensure the Typings config is set to do mappings.  I need to run NPM start first before this will attach correctly.  But once all that is done it will work.  I was hoping though that there was a way to do this with NPM start launch config.  Point 3 seems to be an aside as I did not have to have it and your point 4 really only needs the first config to effectively debug Typescript.  Other than that though your config will attach effectively to the Typescript so if no one provides anything better you get the answer.

Comment: You can have `ng server` in your `package.config` and then run npm start before debug, I will add it to answer. and your're right `typescript` mapping is needed but it isn't related to `VSCode` debugging, that is necessary even if you want to debug in developer tools.

Comment: I was struggling with this, it helps a lot. if you do not mind, could I ask why put # after http://localhost:4200/?